# Extraction directory of Ruby application via OCRA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ocra

I'm using OCRA (One Click Ruby Application) to create a portable Ruby on Rails application. I encountered an error that goes like this:

```
missing helper file helpers/application_helper.rb helper.rb
```

This error is related to case sensitivity issue with Ruby 2.2, where using `C:\User\Sites` would cause an error.

I upgraded ruby to 2.3, but the error retains. I noticed that some of the characters were changed as well (dot to dash, `ocr.xxx` becomes `ocr-xxx`).

Is there a way to specify to which directory OCRA should be extracting the code? I was thinking of placing it somewhere other than the TEMP directory, which seems to be an issue for me.